# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_is_block_theme()

Tags: wordpress-theming

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_is_block_theme() in /home/vol12_4/epizy.com/epiz_26959882/htdocs/wp-admin/menu.php:205 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol12_4/epizy.com/epiz_26959882/htdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(158): require() #1 /home/vol12_4/epizy.com/epiz_26959882/htdocs/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/vol12_4/e...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/vol12_4/epizy.com/epiz_26959882/htdocs/wp-admin/menu.php on line 205